# why pointer doesn't change its value in C?

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
void func(char *c){
    c = 'B';
    printf("s en func: %c\n", c);
}
int main()
{
    char *s = 'A';
    printf("s en main: %c\n", s);
    func(s);
    printf("s en main 2: %c\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like an output like this:

```
s en main: A

s en func: B

s en main 2: B
```

but i have this:

```
s en main: A

s en func: B

s en main 2: A
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: I suggest that you [enable all compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/12149471) and pay attention to them. I'm reasonably certain that your compiler would not accept your code without giving you a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *s = 'A';
```

Your program is undefined as soon as you access `*s`, which you never did. You just used it as a character.

You seem to want

```
void func(char *c){
    *c = 'B';
    printf("s en func: %c\n", *c);
}
int main()
{
    char value = 'A';
    char *s = &value;
    printf("s en main: %c\n", *s);
    func(s);
    printf("s en main 2: %c\n", *s);

    return 0;
}
```

That is, filling in `*` everywhere to follow the pointer and declaring a variable to hold the initial 'A'.

Comment: I updated main 
    char value = 'A';
    char *s= &value;

    printf("s en main: %c\n", *s);
    func(&s);
    printf("s en main 2: %c\n",*s);

Comment: i 've got same restults.

Comment: sorry i updated func , and now is working. thanks